# Is it guaranteed that there's no padding between values of the same type?

Tags: c, struct, language-lawyer, padding

Consider this code:

```
// T is *any* type
struct str_T{
    T a, b;
};
```

I know that there's (almost always) padding between objects with different alignments because both members are of type `T`. But this time there's no different alignments. Can this assertion always pass?

```
static_assert(sizeof(str_T) == 2 * sizeof(T));
// i.e. padding-free
```

Comment: Related question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47324044/why-is-there-no-padding-in-the-structure-for-only-char-type-members

Comment: Is it true that `_Alignof(str_T::a) == _Alignof(str_T::b)`?

Comment: Even if there is no padding between `struct` members, what about possible padding at the end of the `struct`? This would also be counted in the result of `sizeof`.

Comment: @chux No, different struct types may certainly have different alignment requirements.  Read your quote again:  It's talking about *pointers* to structs, not the structs themselves.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is not guaranteed.
Compiler can always decide to pad or to not pad extra bits between struct members. (Unless overridden)

Quoting from [C11 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), **6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers**

> Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members and the units in
>   which bit-fields reside have addresses that increase in the order in
>   which they are declared. A pointer to a structure object, suitably
>   converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a
>   bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa.
>   **There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its
>   beginning**

Comment: So `T` may be `char` and `struct str_T` sized to 4 for some reason?

Comment: @chux Yes, this is a possibility. But being unspecified, I cannot quote an example of a compiler + flag requirement which can guarantee this behaviour.

Comment: So your conclusion is that it's not specified, but so far no implementation disobeys it?

Comment: @iBug Yes you are right. I am not aware of any implementation where the static assert would fail. But if it allowed to fail on conformant implementations.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, There is no guaranteed that it's the same memory layout.

**C11 6.7.2.1(p6):**

> a structure is a type consisting of a sequence of members, whose
>   storage is allocated in an ordered sequence

The standard doesn't enforce any layouting rules.